# Open clicked link in another div using AngularJS and AJAX

Tags: ajax, angularjs, playframework-2.0

I have a Play framework project using AngularJS for its views.

The main page shows a list of items, and it has 2 columns, one for the items' names, other for the clicked item's details. By the time it is loaded, the page already has every item and detail, since it is fed with a JSON containing all information (so, hopefully, I don't need another request, though I can do that if necessary)

This is the controller responsible for "feeding" the main page with JSON:

```
app.controller("ListCtrl", [ "$scope", "$resource", "apiUrl",
        function($scope, $resource, apiUrl) {
            var Servicos = $resource(apiUrl + "/servicos");
            $scope.servicos = Servicos.query(); //returns a JSON
        } ]);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="bs-sidebar hidden-print" role="complementary">
            <ul class="nav bs-sidenav">
                <li><a href="/create"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
                <li ng-repeat="s in servicos | orderBy:'nome'"><a
                    href="/edit/{{s.id}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a><a
                    href="" id="itemName">{{s.nome}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" role="main">

        <div class="bs-docs-section">
            <div class="page-header" id="detail">
                <!-- servicos details go here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to click at the **itemName** link, and the details would be shown at the **detail** div.

Is this possible?
If not and I have to request the clicked item's information when it gets clicked, can someone give me pointers on how to do it? I tried, with no success, to create an AJAX based controller for AngularJS to deal with this. 
Any help will be most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need ngInclude:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Or if you have the HTML in the Javascript and just want to show that: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml